# Bind a tcp socket below 1000 with a non root user using Systemd, java and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, java, systemd, root, socket

I wanted to try socket activation with Systemd and Java on my ubuntu server 16.04. My idea is to make my program able to open directly a standard socket number with a user that is not root.

I currently use the iptable NAT rules, but I wanted to put it away after reading [the article of liquidat](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/howto-run-programs-as-non-root-user-on-privileged-ports-via-systemd/) and this one from [Pid Eins](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html),

My test environement is pretty simple. I've got the following java program :

```
package com.test.bindTCP;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class App 
{

private static void acceptConnection(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    while (true) {
        try (
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(inputLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    ) {
        acceptConnection(serverSocket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I can call it though the following command line : 
`java -cp target/bindTCP-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.bindTCP.App 60606`

It echoes all commands sent though tcp, it's able to serve only one client at time. I tested with "nc" and it work properly on socket upper than 1000.

To set my systemd deamon, I wrote the following config files :

`cat /lib/systemd/system/bindTCP.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=bindTCP Java 23

[Socket]
ListenStream=23
```

`cat /lib/systemd/system/bindTCP.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=bindTCP service
Requires=bindTCP.socket
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mylogin
Group=mygroup

ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java8-jdk-amd64/bin/java  -cp /home/mylogin/bindTCP-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.bindTCP.App 23
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=bindTCP
Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`cat /etc/rsyslog.d/bindTCP.conf`

```
$template bindTCPlog,"%msg%\n"
if $programname == 'bindTCP' then /var/log/bindTCP.log;bindTCPlog
if $programname == 'bindTCP' then stop
```

Then I reload my systemctl config :
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

I restart rsyslog deamon :
`sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`

And then, I try to start my own service 
`sudo systemctl start bindTCP`

But it doen't work, in my log (`/var/log/bindTCP.log`), I found the following java stacktrace

```
 java.net.BindException: Permission denied (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at com.test.bindTCP.App.main(App.java:38)
```

Any idea how to setup my service properly ?

EDIT: [A solution based on authbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux#answer-27989419) is working. The one proposed with setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' doesn't change anything. Clearly systemd is able to deal with this issue, so I'm still looking for a solution 100% based on Systemd. I'm thinking is more secure.

Answer (score 4):

You’re not actually using the systemd-provided socket in your daemon. Instead of creating a new `ServerSocket`, use `System.inheritedChannel()` and check if it’s a `ServerSocketChannel`. If yes, you inherited a socket from systemd and can start to `accept()` connections on that, otherwise you can still create a new `ServerSocket` or `ServerSocketChannel` (e. g. for development purposes). Note that for this to work, you need to set `StandardInput=socket` on the service unit: Java expects the inherited channel to be file descriptor 0 (inetd style), but systemd by default adds sockets starting at file descriptor 3.

Alternatively, you can add this to your service file (in the `Service` section):

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

This will allow Java to allocate reserved port numbers itself. Using a socket unit is definitely the better choice, though. (If you want to use `AmbientCapabilities`, you’ll have to disable the socket unit, because systemd and your service can’t both bind to the same port. That’s probably why the `setcap` suggestion didn’t work.)

---

Side note: since your unit files are managed by you, the system administrator, and not by the package manager, they belong in `/etc`, not in `/lib` (that is, `/etc/systemd/system/bindTCP.{service,socket}`).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setcap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) to allow the java binary itself the [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to bind to privileged ports, without the requirement to be running as `root`:

```
`sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java8-jdk-amd64/bin/java`
```

Comment: this is not working in my case.

Comment: Note that this grants the capability to *any Java program*. `setcap` on interpreter binaries is generally not a good idea.